# HSQLDb to PostgresDb Migration with binary data

Tags: postgresql, csv, hsqldb

I am having a table in Hsql DB which now I am migrating to Postgres.
For this I export a CSV (using SQLSquirrel) from Hsql and import into Postgres using the COPY..FROM postgres command.
I have an attribute of Type `VARBINARY` in the hsql table (lets call it "attr1"), which in Postgres table becomes Type `bytea`.

Suppose one row has the value of attr1 as `\x00` in the hsqldb. The exported CSV contains the value as `00`. But after importing it into Postgres it gets converted to `\x3030` (when viewed in hex format).
For importing CSV into Postgres I use the command as :
`\COPY <tablename> FROM 'Data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

What am I missing ? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the same program to export from HSQLDB and import into PostgreSQL.

The HSQLDB SqlTool can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks fredt. I tried to use SQLSquirrel to import the created CSV but got error as `ERROR: column 'x' is of type smallint but expression is of type character varying` on line 1 itself.

Comment: I also tried using the SqlTool but as I mentioned the data contains binary data hence using the tool gives `Table has a binary column.  DSV files are text, not binary, files.`. The binary column is for which I am facing issues. Any other thing I need to check ? Appreciate your help.